# Typesafe Ids with Spring Data JPA and Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

How would one implement typesafe Ids with Entities in Kotlin:

```
@Entity
data class Example(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: ExampleId,
    val exampleProperty: String,
...){...}
```

So far I only found R2DBC Examples. But none using 'plain' spring-data-jpa.

Comment: do you mean a composite id? What's your `ExampleId` type? Can the database generate it? (`@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)`)

Comment: Example ID should be something like a data class with the ID property as Long nested inside it. So I can write typesafe repositories and stuff.

Basically an embedded ID. Maybe that is my solution :D Just googeled @EmbeddedId: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-embedded-method-parameters

I guess this is something I might want to try out. We had something similar in a quarkus project. I am currently playing around with some springboot kotlin private project stuff.